# Load ngController on MVC view page

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have a MVC view page that I am loading in aspx page

```
$('#example').load('Transcript/Index');
```

now on the Index.cshtml when I am loading the angular controller it is not getting loaded

Comment: What's in the template? Are there any errors in the console? Why are you using Jquery to load pages?

Comment: any code to look at?